# Как подключить в скрипте ключ локализации?

Tags: c#, unity3d, локализация

У меня есть скрипт, который записывает текст который я пишу в текстовую переменную, но я хочу сделать так чтобы в этом поле указывался ключ локализации

```
using UnityEngine;
 
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "NewStoryScene", menuName = "Data/New Story Scene")]
[System.Serializable]
public class StoryScene : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<Sentence> sentences;
    public Sprite background;
    public StoryScene nextScene;
 
    [System.Serializable]
 
    public struct Sentence
    {
        public string text;
        public Speaker speaker;
    }
}
```

Во втором скрипте в методе PlayNextSentence я воспроизвожу текст.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
 
public class BottomBarController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI barText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI personaNameText;
 
    private int sentenceIndex = -1;
    private StoryScene currentScene;
    private State state = State.COMPLETED;
 
    private enum State
    {
        PLAYING, COMPLETED
    }
 
    public void PlayScene(StoryScene scene)
    {
        currentScene = scene;
        sentenceIndex = -1;
        PlayNextSentence();
    }
 
    public void PlayNextSentence()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TypeText(currentScene.sentences[++sentenceIndex].text));
        personaNameText.text = currentScene.sentences[sentenceIndex].speaker.speakerName;
        personaNameText.color = currentScene.sentences[sentenceIndex].speaker.textColor;
    }
 
    public bool IsCompleted()
    {
        return state == State.COMPLETED;
    }
 
    public bool IsLastSentence()
    {
        return sentenceIndex + 1 == currentScene.sentences.Count;
    }
 
    private IEnumerator TypeText(string text)
    {
        barText.text = "";
        state = State.PLAYING;
        int wordIndex = 0;
 
        while (state != State.COMPLETED)
        {
            barText.text += text[wordIndex];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
            if (++wordIndex == text.Length)
            {
                state = State.COMPLETED;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А вот картинка ключа локализации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю, как подключить ключи локализации для размещения текста в первом скрипте в поле
public string text;